# Agregar a TemplateField un ImagenButton en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo esto

```
TemplateField imgTemp = new TemplateField();
    imgTemp.ItemTemplate = new ColumnaTemplate("Seleccion");
    imgTemp.EditItemTemplate = new ElementoTemplate("Seleccion");
    imgTemp.HeaderText = "Seleccion";
    GridView1.Columns.Add(imgTemp);
```

Pero me falta completar mi codigo para que quede igual a lo que hace esto

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                           <ItemTemplate >
                               <asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"  Width="70px" 
                                Height="60px" ToolTip="Seleccion" 
                                ImageUrl = "~/View/Imagen/Perfil.JPG" />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes crear una clase que herede de `ITemplate` para poder crear la columna template

En el articulo explico sobre el tema

[[GridView] ITemplate – Columnas definidas en runtime](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/08/gridview-itemplate-columnas-definidas.html)

Se debe definir una clase que herede de ITemplate, luego tienes que asignar esta a las propiedades de `TemplateField` y agregarlo a la coleccion de Columns

```
TemplateField tempDesc = new TemplateField();
tempDesc.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewHeaderTemplate("Descripcion Producto");
tempDesc.ItemTemplate = new GridViewItemTemplate("Descripcion");
tempDesc.EditItemTemplate = new GridViewEditTemplate("Descripcion");
GridView1.Columns.Add(tempDesc);
```

Comment: podrias editar la pregunta y colocar este codigo, entiendo que ElementoTemplate seria la clase que hereda de ITemplate, no?

Comment: Hola leandro  .... ya en la grilla me aparece una columna que agregue como templateField pero quiero asociarle el imagenButtomn

Comment: Hola Leandro..Ya tengo la el buttonImagen en el template ...pero como puedo agregar el evento rowcommand

Comment: el rowcommand lo defines a nivel del gridview, en el imagebutton solo debes definir el CommandName

Comment: Todavia no se ejecuta lo unico que me falta definir en el imagen btton es el runat="server"  no c com hacerlo pero eestoy casi seguro q  es eso

Comment: si creas una instancia de un ImageButton este es un web control no necesitas especificar el runet=server. De casualidad defines esto dentro de un UpdatePanel ?